# Using JWT authentication with Django/DRF and Storing JWTs in HttpOnly Cookies

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am trying to build a web app using Django and DRF at the back-end and ReactJs at the front end and I want to keep them separate (i.e. avoid Server Side Rendering).For authentication purposes, I want to employ JWT and I am using djangorestframework-jwt for that. I have read it at several places that it is not secure to store JWTs in the local storage so I am trying to use HttpOnly cookies for that. One can achieve that by configuring the django server to send HttpOnly by overriding the following default settings of the drf-jwt package in the settings.py file of your project `JWT_AUTH = { 'JWT_AUTH_COOKIE': '<cookie name>', }` which is set to none by default. The server sends the httpOnly cookie as anticipated but there are a few issues I am facing:

**1.Same Domain Restraint**

I am aware that httpOnly cookies wont be attached to the request headers unless the request is being made to the server which is hosted on the some domain. In my case I am using `localhost:8000` for django and `localhost:3000` for my react project so the browser doesnt attach the cookie as the request is made to a different port. I tried running both app on port 3000 simultaneously, and the browser did attach the cookie in the header and I did get the a `302` response from the server. However, it opened door to all sorts of problems due domain clash. I reckon I can solve this problem using nginx reverse proxy or something like that but I am not sure about it. Do guide me how can I serve both apps on the same host during the development.

**2. Token Refresh Problem**

When I refer to the view setup to refresh the token, I run into a bad request error even when the browser does attach the cookie along the request header. This is the server response in the browser

```
{"token":["This field is required."]}
```

Thanks if for reading it all the way down here!

Answer (score 1):

In order for things to be secure:

- You need [CORS](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/) (Quickstart: CORS_ALLOWED_HOSTS=["http://localhost:3000"], CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS=True)
- The short-lived token (session) cookie (5-15mins), should **NOT** have HTTP-ONLY setting
- The refresh token cookie **SHALL** have HTTP-ONLY setting

Then your basic flow is:

- On login Django creates session token and sends it
- Your SPA reads the cookie and adds its value to the authorization header (Authorization: JWT ...token...)
- Any request to Django should be made with that Authorization header

The refresh flow is:

- Send a request to the refresh token endpoint following the documentation of the library you use
- Django then reads the HTTP-ONLY cookie and verifies it
- If valid, Django sends a new refresh token as HTTP-ONLY cookie along with a new short-lived token session cookie
- Once the refresh token has expired, you log the user out.

An [article here](https://hasura.io/blog/best-practices-of-using-jwt-with-graphql/) goes into detail using GraphQL, but the cookie part and handling of most of the frontend code you should be able to adapt to REST.